# Merging abitrary SVGs in one DOM

Tags: dom, svg, uniqueidentifier

If more then one SVG is used inside a single DOM, eg. inline SVGs inside SVGs or inline SVGs inside HTML documents, they share the same id namespace. So documents working perfectly fine may be broken after merging into a single DOM. 
It seems needed to process the SVGs for merging in some way to replace id's with unique ones.

But how to keep all references? There may be `xlink:href` attributes on `use` tags naming id's. Then there may be stranger constructs like `mask="url(#some_id)"` and so on.

Is there any programmatic way to keep track of id references in an SVG document?

Comment: Just wonder what practical use case do you mean here, any examples? And did you mean that any arbitrary svgs are being merged?

Comment: For example, if a web page is composed of different SVGs, but they need to be scriptable (eg. contain buttons and so on). They can't be included by `img` tags then but must be part of the DOM to attach event handlers and show / hide elements etc.